# clone( ) system call not working correctly

Tags: linux, clone

I have been spending a lot of time on knowing the way to use the `clone()` system call in `linux`. I wrote the following program and it wasn't working correctly....

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<signal.h>
#include<sched.h>
#include<sys/types.h>

int sched2()
{
printf("it is working\n");

}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
printf("in the main\n");
void *stack=malloc(65536);
int Pid=clone(sched2, stack, 0, NULL);
printf("%d\n",Pid );
if(Pid==-1)
{
    printf("clone error\n");
    exit(1);
}
sleep(100);

printf("yea2");
exit(0);
}
```

As I expected, the string `it is working` should be printed... along with...

```
in the main
2534
```

It wasn't printing the `it is working` string. Moreover when I took the process ID of the newly created kernel thread and issued

```
kill -9 2534
```

and I checked the processes on the terminal using ps command and it should like this...

```
 PID    TTY       TIME CMD
2209 pts/2    00:00:00 bash
2533 pts/2    00:00:00 a.out
2534 pts/2    00:00:00 a.out <defunct>
2535 pts/2    00:00:00 ps
```

The process actually isn't killed!! Its still running... Please throw some light...Thank you...

Comment: `wait(50)` (in `sched2`) probably doesn't do what you think it does...

Comment: Actually you are right... thats the reason I edited and removed it...anyways thanks alot.. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> void *stack=malloc(65536);
> int Pid=clone(sched2, stack, 0, NULL);
> ```

On most architectures the stack grows downwards. You'll likely want to say:

```
clone(sched2, stack + 65536, 0, NULL);
```

For the second question, the process *is* dead but the parent hasn't waited for it. It's a so-called "zombie" process.

Comment: you are right, absolutely!!!!.... thanks alot....but one small doubt, if I had written the former way... why didn't I get an error??

Answer (score 0):

It's dead, but the parent forgot to reap it. Use one of the `wait(2)` functions to do so, optionally setting a `SIGCHLD` handler.